# Adjusting only the banner image and not the other images on drupal commerce kickstart 2 using css

Tags: css, image, drupal

I am building an ecommerce site on commerce kickstart 2 and trying to change the margin of the logo image in the header on my subtheme css file.  However, when I change the margin to -200 on the img file, it moves both the banner image and the slide show image.  I tried using element instead of img in the css code, but that made no changes. Here is my current css code for images.

```
img {
    border: 0 none;
    height: 400px;
    margin-left: -200px;
    padding-left: 0;
    padding-right: 0;
    width: 1560px;
}
```

If you look below, the code above changed the margin of the dark banner at the top and the white image at the bottom of the screen shot. I want the white image to stay centered.

[image: Website image, top image is in the correct location, the bottom is not and needs to be centered]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to make CSS specific to the logo's div. So if your logo is in a div with a class="logo-img" you would use.

```
.logo-img img {
    border: 0 none;
    height: 400px;
    margin-left: -200px;
    padding-left: 0;
    padding-right: 0;
    width: 1560px;
}
```

If your logo is in a div with a ID="logo" you would use.

```
#logo img {
    border: 0 none;
    height: 400px;
    margin-left: -200px;
    padding-left: 0;
    padding-right: 0;
    width: 1560px;
}
```